# Is defining the HTML font-size using a linear function a good idea?

Tags: css, responsive-design, compatibility, viewport-units, css-calc

I'm experimenting with CSS and responsive design.
The way I learnt about making a website generally responsive is to set the root font-size at 62.5% of the original meaning that 1rem will be = 10px. Then, with media queries, I will decrease (or increase) the root font-size according to the screen resolution, and the rest of the design that is set in rems will scale accordingly. Great.

But what about adapting the concept of [fluid responsive typography](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/05/fluid-responsive-typography-css-poly-fluid-sizing/)?
In short, the idea is that instead of setting a discrete number of media queries setting for each one a different root font-size in percentages, we use a calc() function and viewport units to set the font-size continuously — in pixels.

One could still use media queries, but only to tweak the curve(s) since CSS calc() only supports linear functions.
Now, I was wondering: is this a good idea for production or should I keep this just a "cool" experiment? What about compatibility?

Thank you.

Comment: cool? yes, necessary? depends on the design. And, just wow!